# Discord JS slash command zodError?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Whenever I run my code I get an odd error from my slash command file here is the error.
I have checked for capital names in the slash command and my command handler though I cant seem to figure it out perhaps you can help me?

```
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [],
    "message": "Required"
  }
]
    at handleResult (/home/runner/MI6Agent/node_modules/zod/lib/types.js:28:23)
    at ZodString.safeParse (/home/runner/MI6Agent/node_modules/zod/lib/types.js:140:16)
    at ZodString.parse (/home/runner/MI6Agent/node_modules/zod/lib/types.js:120:29)
    at Y (/home/runner/MI6Agent/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:3:5798)
    at b (/home/runner/MI6Agent/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:3:5893)
    at te.runRequiredValidations (/home/runner/MI6Agent/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:3:6930)
    at te.toJSON (/home/runner/MI6Agent/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:3:7116)
    at /home/runner/MI6Agent/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:3:12954
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MixedClass.toJSON (/home/runner/MI6Agent/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:3:12945)
    at /home/runner/MI6Agent/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:3:13239
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MixedClass.toJSON (/home/runner/MI6Agent/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:3:13230)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/MI6Agent/index.js:33:30)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

Here is my slash command.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('inform')
    .setDescription('Informs the specified user in DMs.')
    .addSubcommand(command => command
      .setName('channel')
      .setDescription('Sends a message to an channel')
      .addChannelOption(option => option.setName('target').setDescription('Select the target channel').setRequired(true)).addBooleanOption(option => option.setName('incognito').setRequired(true)))
    .addSubcommand(command => command
      .setName('member')
      .setDescription('Sends a message to an member')
      .addUserOption(option => option.setName('target').setDescription('Select the target user').setRequired(true)).addBooleanOption(option => option.setName('incognito').setRequired(true)))
  .addSubcommand(command => command
      .setName('role')
      .setDescription('Sends a message to an member')
      .addRoleOption(option => option.setName('target').setDescription('Select the target role').setRequired(true)).addBooleanOption(option => option.setName('incognito').setRequired(true))),
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a hint in the error: it received `undefined` but expected a string. This means you're missing something (rather than something being an invalid string e.g. with capital letters).

You need to add descriptions for the `incognito` boolean option (add a `.setDescription()` to the method chain).

For more information on what fields are required for commands and their options, see the [Discord API docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#application-command-object-application-command-option-structure).